# Why my jQuery script executes just once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, href, datapicker

I have a problem with my jQuery UI datepicker. I have this code :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#datepickerFrom').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
      inline: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
          day = date.getDate(),
          month = date.getMonth() + 1,
          year = date.getFullYear();

        var url = $('#reservation').attr('href');
        url = url.replace('05&', day + '&');
        $('#reservation').attr('href', url);

        var url2 = $('#reservation').attr('href');
        url2 = url2.replace('12', month);
        $('#reservation').attr('href', url2);

        var url3 = $('#reservation').attr('href');
        url3 = url3.replace('2016', year);
        $('#reservation').attr('href', url3);
      }
    });

    $('#datepickerTo').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
      inline: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
          day = date.getDate(),
          month = date.getMonth() + 1,
          year = date.getFullYear();

        var url4 = $('#reservation').attr('href');
        url4 = url4.replace('=2016', '=' + year);
        $('#reservation').attr('href', url4);

        var url5 = $('#reservation').attr('href');
        url5 = url5.replace('13', +month);
        $('#reservation').attr('href', url5);

        var url6 = $('#reservation').attr('href');
        url6 = url6.replace('09', day);
        $('#reservation').attr('href', url6);

      }
    });
  });
</script>
<p>Date arrivée :
  <input type="text" id="datepickerFrom">
</p>
<p>Date départ :
  <input type="text" id="datepickerTo">
</p>

<a id="reservation" class="et_pb_button  et_pb_button_0 et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="https://mywebsite.com/book?shs&chkin=2016-12-05&chkout=2016-13-09&step=1">Réservez</a>
```

When I click on a date (datepickerTo and datepickerFrom), it updates my href link but only one time. When I change the date, the script is not executed.

Comment: It's because you are searching for a static value: `url = url.replace('05&', day + '&');`, when you change the date the first time to a day != 5 the `replace` function will not find something to replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works only at the first time since you search for the inital values and replace them. Check this code of yours:

```
var url = $('#reservation').attr('href');
url = url.replace('05&', day + '&');
$('#reservation').attr('href', url);
var url2 = $('#reservation').attr('href');
url2 = url2.replace('12', month);
$('#reservation').attr('href', url2);
var url3 = $('#reservation').attr('href');
url3 = url3.replace('2016', year);
$('#reservation').attr('href', url3);
```

It basically replaces '05' what the given day, '12' with the given month and '2016' with the given year. When the user chooses a different date this code finds nothing to replace with this new date.

Comment: Upvote done ;)

But I don't know how to dynamicly update my href link, do you have an idea ? 

This href will always "&chkin=2016-12-05&chkout=2016-13-09&step=1" at the beginning....

Comment: I would not replace the href but rather get the new day, month and year of the dates (in both fields), and rewrite the href value each time.

Comment: Something like this ? 

url = "https://mywebsite.com/book?shs&chkin=" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "&chkout=" + year2 + "-" + month2 + "-" + day2 + "&step=1"

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Thank's a lot, I'll try it !

Comment: @PierreMétéyé, please remember to always upvote the helpful answers.